# Image Flickering In Canvas Game

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

For a university project I have been tasked with creating a Flappy Bird clone. It's being done using the HTML5 canvas.

The issue doesn't happen very often, but it seems that every 6 or so seconds, the grass will flicker. I'm not sure what's causing this, it could be a performance issue.

Here is a link so you may see the issue: http://canvas.pixcelstudios.uk

Here is the function I'm using to the draw the grass:

```js
var drawGrass = function(cWidth, ctx, minusX)
{
 var x = bg_grass.x;
 var y = bg_grass.y;
 var w = bg_grass.w;
 var h = bg_grass.h;
 var img = bg_grass.img;

 if (minusX[0] >= cWidth)
 {
  bg_grass.x = 0;
  minusX[0] = 0;
 }

 ctx.drawImage(img, x, y, w, h);

 if (minusX[0] > 0)
 {
  ctx.drawImage(img, w-minusX[0], y, w, h);
 }
};
```

Basically, I'm drawing two grass sprites, each taking up a canvas width. One starts with an X of 0 and the other starts at the end of the canvas. Both are decremented each frame, then one is completely off the screen, it's completely reset to keep it looping.

I don't think it's anything to do with my update loop which is as follows:

```js
this.update = function()
 {
  clearScreen();
  updateBackground();
  updatePositions();
  checkCollisions();
  render();
  requestAnimFrame(gameSpace.update);
 };
```

I've done a little bit of reading and I've read about having a second canvas to act as a buffer. Apparently this can stop flickering and improve performance? But all of the examples I've seen show the parts being drawn into the canvas out of a loop and I can't really see how doing it within a game loop (moving parts and all) would increase performance rather than decrease it. Surely the same operations are being performed, except now you also have to draw the second canvas onto the first?

Please let me know if you need any more information (although you should be able to see the whole source from the web link).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found the issue! Was just a simple mistake in my drawGrass function.

Due to the ordering, there'd be just a single frame where I'd set my shorthand X variable to bg_grass.x and THEN set bg_grass.x to something else, therefore drawing the wrong value.

I've now set my shorthand variables after the first if-statement.

However, if anyone could provide any insight into the second part of the question regarding a buffer canvas, I'd still much appreciate that.